# discrete groupoid

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

[Here](https://thosgood.com/blog/2017/12/11/spectra-part-2.html)
they say:

First of all, since A is a discrete groupoid, the only morphisms are of the form $\text{id}⁣:x\to x$
Also, here is the definition of discrete category in ncatlab:

```
A category is discrete if it is both a groupoid and a preorder.
```

I would say that there might be a $x$ and a $y$ with $x\neq y$ and $\text{hom}(x,y)=\star$.

So in my view there are definitely more morphisms than $\text{id}_x⁣:x\to x$!

Comment: I guess by $*$ you mean a one-element set. Since ${\rm id}_x$ is already an element, $\hom(x,x)$ can have no more elements.

Answer (score 3):

There's a mild disagreement on terminology here. Your first source wants a discrete category to satisfy the axiom that if there's a morphism $f:x\to y$, then $x=y$. The nLab, as usual, is a bit less demanding: their notion of a discrete category is one such that, if there's a morphism $f:x\to y$, then it is unique and an isomorphism. Thus, for instance, the category $a\leftrightarrows b$ generated by two objects with a unique isomorphism between them is discrete for the nLab.

The reason for this gap in terminology is that discrete categories in the sense of the nLab are *equivalent* to categories discrete in the first sense, and the nLab, along with many categorical thinkers, prefers definitions that are invariant under equivalence of categories.

Comment: Could you please have a look [here](https://thosgood.com/blog/2017/12/11/spectra-part-2.html#fnref4) yet at $\Sigma\dashv \Omega$ ? Why ${\cal E}_n\to \Omega{\cal E}_{n+1}$ and not vice versa: ${\cal E}_{n+1}\to \Omega{\cal E}_{n}$ ? I thought that adjunction **reverses** the direction of morphisms.

Comment: @user3357120 You should ask a separate question for this one as it is unrelated to the notion of discrete groupoid. But no, an adjunction does not reverse the direction of morphisms.